# If I create a branch after typing git stash branch what happens?

Tags: git

Specially, after I typed

```
git stash branch
```

I typed

```
git status
```

which returned this:

```
## HEAD (no branch)
?? Project/Setup_BACKUP_38164.swift
?? Project/Setup_BASE_38164.swift
?? Project/Setup_LOCAL_38164.swift
?? Project/Setup_REMOTE_38164.swift
```

I now want to create a new branch that is the same as my stash. I'm wondering if I type

```
git checkout -b *newbranchname
```

From where I currently am in HOME, will this new branch be equal to my stash? Or would I need to do a commit of some sort? Why is the commit necessary if so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
Creates and checks out a new branch named <branchname> starting from the commit at which the <stash> was originally created, applies the changes recorded in <stash> to the new working tree and index. If that succeeds, and <stash> is a reference of the form stash@{<revision>}, it then drops the <stash>. When no <stash> is given, applies the latest one.`

As per the docs, git stash branch creates and checks out the branch for you. After this command you don't have to explicitly checkout any branch

Comment: After I did git stash branch and a git status it returns the code from my answer, saying I'm in HEAD (no branch). How do I go from here to a branch, keeping all my code as is?

Comment: Oh wait. The command should have been git stash branch <branchname>. I see you haven't given the branch name in your command. Can you try again by giving a branch name?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your command as you said: "git stash branch" you should have gotten an error or end up with a strange situation. First you can do:

```
git branch
```

to check in which branch you are right now, if you don't like this branch just checkout the one of interest, then:

```
git status
```

to see if you have unsaved changes (not committed), from there you should be able to tell if your previously stashed changes are applied or not in your current status, if they are applied from there you can create your new branch:

```
git checkout -b "Name of your new branch"
```

and you are good.

If you can't see your stashed changes then do:

```
git stash list
```

and notice the number between curly braces that identify the set of changes you are interested on, in this case you do:

```
git checkout -b "Name of your new branch"
git stash apply {"The Number of stash of interest"}
```